# sqlite3.OperationalError: near “ProductID”: syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create a data for a stock management system for a shop selling Christmas items (yes, I know Christmas has gone, but that's the task). My code is as below:

```
import sqlite3

def existing_table(table_name,sql):
    response = input("The table {0} already exists. Do you wish to recreate it? (Y/N)")
    if response.upper() == "Y":
        keep_table = False
        print("The {0} table will be recreated. All existing data will be erased.".format(table_name))
        cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format(table_name))
        db.commit()
    elif response.upper() == "N":
        print("The existing table was kept.")
    else:
        existing_table(table_name,sql)
    if not keep_table:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()

def create_table(db_name,table_name,sql):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where name=?",(table_name,))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        keep_table = True
        if len(result) == 1:
            existing_table()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db_name = "XmasShop.db"
    sql = """create table Product
            ProductID integer,
            Name text,
            Price real,
            primary key(ProductID)"""
    create_table(db_name,"Product",sql)
```

However, when I run it, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 36, in <module>
    create_table(db_name,"Product",sql)
line 26, in create_table
    cursor.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ProductID": syntax error
```

What's wrong here, and how can this be solved?
(Bear in mind I'm a first year A-level student, so any reasoning behind your solution and my problem is extremely helpful!)

EDIT: There is no data in the table yet. This will be added later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception hints that it's an SQLite syntax error. Indeed, if you compare your `CREATE TABLE` statement against the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), you'll find that the syntax requires parentheses around the column definitions, such as:

```
sql = """create table Product
        (ProductID integer,
        Name text,
        Price real,
        primary key(ProductID))"""
```

Comment: So basic! I should have known better.